# How can I fix 1064 (4200) error I am getting while updating my password?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a fresh installation of MySQL 5.7.12. When I try to update the password for the root user using

```
mysql> use mysql;
Database changed 
mysql> update mysql.user set password = password<'mynewpass'> where user = 'root';
```

I am getting this error-

```
"Error 1064(42000): You have error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'where user = 'root'' at line 1.
```

Comment: Why the less than/greater than symbols?

Comment: try: update mysql.user set password = password('mynewpass') where user = 'root';

Comment: I get this error when i try that ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '‍‍password' in 'field list'. I tried using authentication_string instead of password it runs successfully but the login doesn't work. I can still login with the root user without password(i created an insecure DB in the beginning)